# HTML- Form -<textarea> is breaking the alignment in the table layout

Tags: html

In HTML I am making a form where there are 2 tables side by side. In one table all the form `<label>/Name/E Mail/Password</label>` and in another table I am trying to put the form `<inputs>` text/email/password to make them look nicely visible.

But when I gave the label Message and `<textarea name="Message" rows="1" cols="30"></text area>` my whole form layout is getting disturbed due to which I am not able keep my initial labels and inputs aligned.

```
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <label>Name</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>Email</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>Password</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>Message</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="email" name="" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <textarea name="Message" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
          </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

[When the labels and inputs are aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1GXV.png)
[When the labels and inputs are not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy16b.png)

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: [You should not use tables for layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/215552). [Let me repeat that again. You should not use tables for layout.](http://www.shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/). If you must, use a single table with two columns, not three tables...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the extra table inside of the table, and you are including everything inside of 1 row, which is why its formatted like that.

You shouldn't be using tables for this, not when you have things like [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).  Here is a [basic example](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-responsive-forms-with-flexbox--cms-26767) of using flexbox with a form.

But if you must use a table, try a table format like this ...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>label here</td>
        <td>form field here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label here</td>
        <td>form field here</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Here is an example using your code.

```html
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Email</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="email" name="" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Message</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="Message" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Added the code, Please correct me where i am wrong.